# Проверка текстового условия в запросе

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица юзеров с полями `date_created, contract_type`.

Мне нужно вывести в запросе всех юзеров, у которых истек контракт.

Нужно делать проверку по полю `contract_type`, которое может иметь два значения: `M2M` — 30 дней, `Annual` — год.

Как в данный запрос добавить условия для типов контракта и проверить, не истёк ли контракт?

```
SELECT u.id, u.dateCreated, DATE(NOW()) as date_now, c.name
FROM users u
JOIN contract_type c
ON u.contract_type = c.id 
WHERE u.contract_type is not null
```

Собственная попытка решения:

Вроде что то сам надумал, только на CONCAT ругается, подскажите где ошибка.Спасибо конечно за верный ответ, просто хотел сам тоже попробовать решить проблему.

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.dateCreated, DATE(NOW()) as date_now, c.name,
CASE c.name WHEN "M2M" THEN 'MONTH' ELSE "YEAR" END as type_value
FROM users u
JOIN contract_type c
ON u.contract_type = c.id
HAVING date_now > u.dateCreated + INTERVAL CONCAT("1", type_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверка `u.contract_type is not null` — излишняя, так как вы делаете `join` по этому полю.

например, можно сделать так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d6ea/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table u (u int, d date, cid int);

insert into u values
   (1, '2015-01-01', 1)
  ,(2, '2015-01-01', 2)
  ,(3, '2014-01-01', 1)
  ,(4, '2015-08-01', 2)
  ,(5, '2014-01-01', null)
;

create table c (cid int, t text);

insert into c values
   (1, 'annual')
  ,(2, 'm2m')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select u.u, u.d, c.t from u
join c
  on c.cid = u.cid
where
 c.t = 'annual' and u.d < date_sub(now(), interval 1 year)
 or
 c.t = 'm2m' and u.d < date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d6ea/3/0)**:

```
| u |                         d |      t |
|---|---------------------------|--------|
| 2 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |    m2m |
| 3 | January, 01 2014 00:00:00 | annual |
```

Comment: Проверка на Null не совсем лишняя,так как в базе могут быть юзеры без контракта.

Comment: по-простому говоря, `join` уже «включает» эту проверку.