# Mysql выборка связанных данных

Tags: mysql

В продолжение вопроса: [Проверка текстового условия в запросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445333/178576)

---

Есть таблица пользователей, и каждый из них, в свою очередь, может выдать лицензию другому пользователю.

В итоге в бд есть следующие поля:

> Id,created_by,date_created,contract_type

Я хочу выбрать всех пользователей, у который истек срок лицензии, и тех пользователей, которым была выдана лицензия данным пользователем. Если истекает лицензия у пользователя, который выдал лецензию, автоматически истекает и у всех получивших.

На данный момент есть такой вариант запроса, но он не выводит то что надо:

```
SELECT u.id,u.email,u.dateCreated,c.name,u.created_by
 FROM users u 
JOIN contract_type c
 ON u.contract_type = c.id  
 WHERE( c.name = 'M2M' AND u.dateCreated < date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
OR c.name = 'Annual' AND u.dateCreated < date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
  AND u.created_by = u.id
```

Как изменить этот запрос, чтобы отображались и пользователи, получившие лицензию от пользователя с истёкшей лицензией?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так добавьте соответствующее условие:

```
SELECT u.id,u.email,u.dateCreated,c.name
FROM users u
JOIN contract_type c
ON u.contract_type = c.id
WHERE (
c.name = 'M2M' AND u.dateCreated < date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
OR c.name = 'Annual' AND u.dateCreated < date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
) and u.created_by = номер
```

---

пример на sqlfiddle. второй запрос выбирает только тех, у кого `created_by` равно `1`, третий запрос выбирает всех, у кого истекла либо «своя» лицензия, либо лицензия «создателя»:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d841/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table u (u int, d date, cid int, created_by int);

insert into u values
   (1, '2015-01-01', 1, null)
  ,(2, '2015-01-01', 2, null)
  ,(3, '2015-01-01', 1, 1)
  ,(4, '2015-01-01', 2, 1)
  ,(5, '2015-08-01', 1, 2)
  ,(6, '2015-07-01', 2, null)
;

create table c (cid int, t text);

insert into c values
   (1, 'annual')
  ,(2, 'm2m')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select u.u, u.d, c.t from u
join c
  on c.cid = u.cid
where
 c.t = 'annual' and u.d < date_sub(now(), interval 1 year)
 or
 c.t = 'm2m' and u.d < date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d841/7/0)**:

```
| u |                         d |   t |
|---|---------------------------|-----|
| 2 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 | m2m |
| 4 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 | m2m |
| 6 |    July, 01 2015 00:00:00 | m2m |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select u.u, u.d, c.t from u
join c
  on c.cid = u.cid
where (
 c.t = 'annual' and u.d < date_sub(now(), interval 1 year)
 or
 c.t = 'm2m' and u.d < date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
) and u.created_by = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d841/7/1)**:

```
| u |                         d |   t |
|---|---------------------------|-----|
| 4 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 | m2m |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select u1.u, u1.d, c1.t, u2.d as creator_date, c2.t as creator_type from u u1
join c c1
  on c1.cid = u1.cid
left join u u2
  on u1.created_by = u2.u
left join c c2
  on c2.cid = u2.cid
where
 c1.t = 'annual' and u1.d < date_sub(now(), interval 1 year)
 or
 c1.t = 'm2m' and u1.d < date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
 or
 c2.t = 'annual' and u2.d < date_sub(now(), interval 1 year)
 or
 c2.t = 'm2m' and u2.d < date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
order by 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d841/7/2)**:

```
| u |                         d |      t |                         d |      t |
|---|---------------------------|--------|---------------------------|--------|
| 2 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |    m2m |                    (null) | (null) |
| 4 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |    m2m | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 | annual |
| 5 |  August, 01 2015 00:00:00 | annual | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |    m2m |
| 6 |    July, 01 2015 00:00:00 |    m2m |                    (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Данный запрос не работает.Получается что я выбираю запись которая соответствует 2-ум условиям,если по одному не проходит запись не выбирается

Comment: Как я понимаю надо делать 2 отдельных запроса? Получается сперва надо выбрать всех юзеров у которых истекла лицензия,а далее на основе этих юзеров выбрать тех юзеров,которым была выдана лицензия! Но можно ли все это одним запросом?

Comment: я и предложил одним запросом. ответ обновлён — добавил тот же запрос, что предлагал вам в ответ на вчерашний вопрос, дополнив его запросом с отбором только тех пользователей, у которых `created_by` равно `1`

Comment: не совсем понимаю почему последний запрос вывел одного юзера,по идее должно 3,самого юзера который приобрел лицензию и еще 2-ух которым выдал,верно?

Comment: с просроченной лицензией – всего два. из них создан пользователем номер `1` – всего один.

Comment: то, что вы написали в последнем комментарии, никак не пересекается с изложенным в вопросе.

Comment: Не знаю почему но у меня не работает ваш запрос,не выводит ничего вообще!

Comment: Ситуация следующая,если у того кто выдал лицензию она истекает,автоматом истекает и у тех кому он выдал!

Comment: это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Извиняюсь что забыл это уточнить изначально!

Comment: внесите, пожалуйста, исправления в вопрос. или задайте новый.

Comment: @quaresma89, дополнил ответ третьим запросом, соответствующим поправке, внесённой в вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо это то что нужно!